# UNDO a git override of my project

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new to git and instead of checking out my project out of bitbucket I manually downloaded it and then pushed it with a --force a few days ago. Now we tried to fix this and removed these commits from the repository. While doing this, we have reverted the project status the the last commit (i guess) and now the actual status is the project status from 2 weeks ago. Can I undo the revert somehow and go back to the status before i set the project back

When I go for git log I get:

```
Admins-iMac:HandyApp admin$ git log
commit 005443e16e9e887084929385dcab1c7cd6897d7a
Author: Admin <admin@Admins-iMac.local>
Date:   Tue Aug 29 15:53:07 2017 +0200

    login and rating system

commit 16ab9e9614c57dfacb94835d88d73ce248b63754
Author: Admin <admin@Admins-iMac.local>
Date:   Tue Aug 29 08:17:16 2017 +0200

    Login and Rating System

commit 92be0bb19d09e9983402b3e443406f3bd3393c27
Author: Admin <admin@Admins-iMac.local>
Date:   Tue Aug 22 16:07:00 2017 +0200
```

None of these commits is available in Bitbucket any more. The project status is at latest local commit. What can I do? Is it even possible to revert this?

Edit:

So what I want: 
I have a project status  (that was after my latest commit, so commit 00544...) and then i pulled the status from that latest commit. So there was a version after that latest commit I did not commit and where I want to go back to. I know that this is possible to revert in eclipse when using Subversion. But I do not know, if it is a git feature. Since I am not using eclipse atm (I am building a {N}-app) I have no idea how I could undo this last command.

Comment: I think these answers might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit

Comment: As far as I can see, these are mainly on reverting to a committed stage, but I reverted to a committed stage and want to undo this (so step back to the non-commited stage before I reverted).

Comment: I see! So you want to revert the last commit? What about these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-commits-in-git

Comment: I am note sure if that's what I want - I have no commit status where I want to revert to, my last status was a new status i would have committed, so it was a later version than my last commit (if that makes sense) and i set my changes back to the last commit (accidently) and now I want to revert the writing-back. I edited my question a little bit.